# Why can't I find the Invoke method body of a delegate in IL code?

Tags: c#, delegates, cil

I decompiled sources for my `TestDelegate`

```cs
public delegate int TestDelegate(int a, int b);
```

When I view this IL code, why can't I find the Invoke method? I can't find other methods in delegate either. How does it work?

```
  .method public hidebysig virtual newslot instance int32
    Invoke(
      int32 a,
      int32 b
    ) runtime managed
  {
    // Can't find a body
  } // end of method TestDelegate::Invoke
```

```cs
     TestDelegate SumDelegate = Sum;
     SumDelegate.Invoke(1, 2);
```

IL:

```
    IL_001c: callvirt     instance int32 Resolvers.Tests.Delegates.TestDelegate::Invoke(int32, int32)
```

Generating IL shows the Invoke method call, I can't find it. What is really going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Invoke(...)` method on a delegate (as well as a few others, like `BeginInvoke(...)` and `EndInvoke(...)`) are implemented by the runtime itself, rather than in your assembly, which is why you don't see a method body when decompiling. These methods have an attribute attached to indicate this, e.g.:

```
[MethodImpl(0, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
public virtual int Invoke(int a, int b);
```

It is of course reasonable to ask how it works "under the hood", though the answer turns out to be quite complex because it depends on the *kind* of method that your delegate is to invoke (e.g. static vs instance methods, virtual vs. non-virtual, etc.) and whether the delegate is "open" or "closed".

Whilst "open" and "closed" aren't terms we normally encounter in the context of delegates, the meaning is relatively straightfoward - a "closed" delegate stores the first argument to the method that will be invoked in the case of a static method, or the instance that the method will be invoked on (i.e. `this`) in the case of an instance method, and an "open" delegate does not. [This post](https://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html) contains more details if you're interested. For simplicity I'll cover only the two types you're most likely to encounter - instance closed and static open delegates.

You may also have noticed in your decompilation that your `TestDelegate` derives from `System.Delegate` (via `System.MulticastDelegate`), and so inherits 4 fields, which you can see described in the .NET Core runtime source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/coreclr/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Delegate.CoreCLR.cs#L17-L32). The following three are most relevant to us:

```
object _target;
IntPtr _methodPtr;
IntPtr _methodPtrAux;
```

It's worth noting that calling `Invoke(...)` on a delegate always does the same thing - it loads the delegate's `_target` as the first argument (for instance methods the first argument is what we normally call `this`), and then calls the method pointed to by `_methodPtr`, this makes delegates to instance methods very simple since it's almost exactly like calling the instance method directly, but complicates things slightly for static methods as we'll see below.

Going with the simplest case first, and using your `TestDelegate` as an example, you'd create an instance closed delegate like this:

```
public class Test
{
    private int _c;

    ...

    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b + _c;
    }
}

...

var testInstance = new Test();
var addDelegate = new TestDelegate(testInstance.Add);
```

The `addDelegate` is an instance closed delegate, since it stores the instance (`testInstance`) on which the `Add(...)` method will be called. In this case, the `_target` field will store `testInstance`, and `_methodPtr` stores the address of the `Test.Add(...)` method.

When you subsequently call `addDelegate.Invoke(...)` (or the equivalent short-form `addDelegate(...)`), `testInstance` is loaded from the `_target` field into `this`, the `Add(...)` method's address is loaded from the `_methodPtr` field, and is called, and so is almost exactly like just calling `testInstance.Add(...)` directly.

For a static open delegate, you'd do something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

var addDelegate = new TestDelegate(Test.Add);
```

Here, `addDelegate` is a static open delegate, and is a slightly more complex scenario. In this case there is no instance because `Test.Add(...)` is static, but since `Invoke(...)` always works the same way, if it were to store a pointer to `Test.Add(...)` in `_methodPtr`, we would have a problem as the arguments would be in the wrong places - the contents of `_target` would be in the first argument position and `a` and `b` would be in the 2nd and 3rd argument positions, when they need to be in the 1st and 2nd.

To get around this problem, the pointer to `Test.Add(...)` is instead put in `_methodPtrAux`, `_target` stores the `addDelegate` itself, and `_methodPtr` contains a pointer to a special method called the "shuffle thunk". When `Invoke(...)` is called, the shuffle thunk handles "shuffling" the arguments into their proper positions, and then calls the real method based on the address stored in `_methodPtrAux`.

Having `Invoke(...)` always do the same thing of course makes calling a delegate simpler from a runtime point of view, but can result in (open) delegates to static methods being slightly slower than (closed) delegates to instance methods due to the overhead of running the shuffle thunk first.

Comment: @EvgeniyTerekhin - you might want to take a look at the delegate implementation in the .NET Core runtime, starting at the [`SetupShuffleThunk`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/coreclr/src/vm/comdelegate.cpp#L712) method. Ultimately the shuffle thunk is native code generated at runtime by one of the platform-specific `EmitShuffleThunk` methods (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/coreclr/src/vm/i386/stublinkerx86.cpp#L3671) for x86/x64).

Answer (score 3):

Because a delegate is a reference to a method, not an actual method.

It doesn't have an implementation on your c# code, so what makes you think it can have any kind of implementation in the generated IL code?

From [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/):

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a compatible signature and return type. You can invoke (or call) the method through the delegate instance.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what is happen when i call Invoke()? 
in other words how is called method in delegate?

Comment: If the delegate is a assigned to a method, it invokes the method the delegate is assigned to. If not, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` for attempting to invoke a null delegate.

Comment: I understand it, I want found out how does it work inside. How is the code calling the method written on byte code?

Comment: Byte code? IL is very far from byte code.... Personally, I don't remember when I last cared about what happens on the IL level, let alone lower levels. I don't know exactly how the runtime manages delegates and I don't really need to know that in order to know how to work with delegates - just like I don't need to know how an internal combustion motor works to know how to drive a car.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense - yes, a delegate is a reference to a method, not a method itself, but `Invoke()` *is* a method, so asking about its implementation is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @Iridium Invoke is a method, but it's late binded - which is exactly why it's possible to use delegates in the first place. The invoke is binded to the implementation at runtime. I don't understand exactly what you disagree about in my answer. Sure, it's not as elaborated and comprehensive as your answer, but that doesn't make it wrong.